# Shall I use a random effect or not?

Tags: random-variable, random-effects-model, glmm, mixed-model

I need to see if in the case I am going to present it is worth to use a random effect or not.

I carried out some bird counts from **9** **elevated lookouts** in an island. Just to orient you, these lookouts offered a wide and unobstructed view over a portion of forest from which birds could be easily spotted and recorded.

I want to investigate the effect of some variables on the counts, like *time of the day*, *area size* and *density of birds in the area* (estimated by distance sampling, a more reliable method for estimating animal abundance and density).

Each lookout has been investigated twice, i.e. I counted birds from each lookout in two different seasons; therefore 9 lookouts x 2 seasons = 18 points.

It seems that I may occur in a pseudoreplication problem. My question is: **can I specify *lookout* as a random factor if I have only two replications for each subject?** Is the model capable to see the intra-subject variation due to only two pseudoreplications?

My idea is to build two models, a linear model without *lookout* as random factor and a linear mixed model with *lookout* as random factor and see what AIC tells me. Is it a good way to test this? If not, how can I do it? And moreover, how to do it in R?

If I simply look at the summary() of the two models, AIC values are very close to each other; anyway, I wonder if there is a command to compare two models of which one is a mixed model.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your (I guess) `lmer` code lines, just out of curiosity? The question is great as it stands.

Comment: 1. Can you clarify how did you use `season`? 2. Can you please clarify the size of your sample?  3. In general AIC is fine as a starting point but it is not a panacea. Given that the AIC are very close I would opt for the simple model but I would probably bootstrap it (use `confint`) to get confidence intervals to the random effects; notice that if their stand. deviation is close to zero the bootstrap CI are not very reliable. 4. Do you use `lmer` or `glmer`? You probably have Poisson count data and not Gaussian ones so `lmer` is inappropriate.

Comment: First of all, thank you for comments. Let's expand the story a bit (probably several questions will come up to me while writing!).

Comment: My aim is to see whether the lookout counts method can be used  as a surrogate for density estimates by distance sampling (the more reliable method for animal abundance and density estimation).

1. I didn't use **season** because there are no significant differences niether between the counts carried out in the two different seasons, nor between the density estimates in the two seasons.

2. Let's rule the *time of the day* and "area size" variables out of the discussion, it would take too long. For some reasons that is useless to explain my sample size is very small, i.e. n=12.

Comment: 3. I don't use Poisson because counts are adjusted per hour per km^2, since counting sessions were longer than one hour and some areas were either larger or smaller than 1km^2.

I have just built a model like following:
**mod1<-lm(counts~density)**. 
In this simple model turns out that *density* (of birds) explain a lot of variability of counts. However, I want to deal with the pseudoreplication issue.
I tried with nlme library:
gls.norandom<-gls(counts~density, data=lookout)
glmm.random<-lme(counts~density,random=~1|lookout,data=lookout_data)

Comment: A) Why using either lme or lme4?
B) How to see if it is worth including the random effect if **AICnorandom=81.1**,**AICrandom=79.3**, **StDev of random effect is *intercept=4.9* and *residual=3.2***? 
C) Why REML and not LM (I know REML gives less biased estimates with small sample size)?

Comment: Sorry I probably misunderstand something: You have save 12 samples in total? Also, you have count data even after the adjustment; why you treat them as Gaussian? Clearly you can't have negative values for example and I somewhat suspect that over-dispersion might be an issue. Use a Poisson regression model. (`glm(er)`, log link function, etc.)

Comment: I've bene told that if numbers are not integer I cannot treat them as Poisson. You're right, even if I adjust them I don't  have negative  values, but they're not integer anymore. What shall I do? Thank you very much.